# html page as a background

Tags: html, css, web

In `html + css`, I want to add `html` page as a page `background`. i created it as a slices from Photoshop then saved it as `html/image.`

I used to use image as a background like:

```
body  
{
background-image:url('../../resources/bacground.png');
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}
```

But now i don't know how to place `html` as a background.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just make the image the background and cut out the page as the background?

Comment: the page contains more than one link so i created it following: http://www.ehow.com/how_5141900_create-hyperlink-photoshop.html

Comment: actually i'm wondering why images cannot contain links

Comment: curious what exactly answer you are looking?

Comment: is there any way to place html page as a background?!

Comment: `position:absolute` will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that now.
However you can save your html as svg and then use

```
html {
  background-image: url(svg-css-background.svg);
}
```

In the future you will have the possibility to import html directly with a link
Perhaps you can also wrap your background html into a div , and make it unresponsive and absolute. And drop the real html on top of it.
I'm not sure if that is what you really want but if you want to use links in an image you can use map + area or this ([svg](http://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/))

```
<map name="map1">
<area
   href="contacts.html" alt="contacts" title="contacts"
   shape=rect coords="6,116,97,184">
<area
   href="new.html" alt="new!" title="new!"
   shape=poly coords="150,217, 190,257, 150,297,110,257">
</map>

<img src="a.jpg"
   alt="image" border=0 width=300 height=300
   usemap="#map1">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Background Image**

One way to do the background is to use `background-size: cover` as per [this post](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer here, what you're probably going to want to do is make the "html background" in a absolutely positioned container, then put a transparent div over the top, then you should be able to place your real html content on top and the background shouldn't be interactive

Answer (score 0):

```
#bgimage
{
background-image:url(..../../image.jpg);
backgroud-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```